# Jgroup port selection control externally

Tags: java, jgroups

We have a Jgroup cluster with tcpgossip protocol as discovery service. Currently each node of the cluster member get assigned with a random TCP port by jgroup
GMS: address=XXX, cluster=cluster, physical address=1.100.102.34:50970

Is there any way we can specify the port range to choose externally without changing the Jgroup configuration. That is using any linux command like iptables rules , can we specify a port range , so that Jgroup will pick ports only from that range

Answer (score 0):

According to the [document](http://www.jgroups.org/manual/html/protlist.html), you can specify the `bind_port` for your configured jgroup transport protocol stack.

> bind_port: The port to which the transport binds. Default of 0 binds to any (ephemeral) port

Example code snippet:

```
<config>
  <TCP
     singleton_name="tcp"
     bind_port=12345
     ...
    />
</config>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually I am looking for a solution which does not need to change anything in source code. I think the above solution requires change in the jgroup configuration XML.